# WOPI : Displaying single page of Word Doc / PPT presentation

Tags: ms-office, ms-wopi

I've got a dummy WOPI app running.
It renders docx, pptx files, but it only displays the first page / slide.

I'm using a office online server on azure, I suspect a config parameter on office server that Im ignoring could be the cause of this (?)

what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such parameter. You can influence whether or not the file opens as read-only but there is no way of telling OOS to only load the first page.

Most likely it'll be one of the following:

- connection issue

  - try looking in the browser's developer console
  - explore Windows Event Viewer of the OOS machine
  - turn off antiviruses and firewalls to rule them out
- [file size limit](http://wopi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/file_sizes.html)
- or just incorrect implementation of the WOPI host (which should also be indicated by the Event Viewer)

Also, test your WOPI host implementation against a local OOS before deploying it to Azure.